# Increment and Decrement Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, function

i made a JavaScript function to increment and decrement a number in the like button, here is the function

```
var val = 0; 
var negative = false;
$('.i-t').click(function(){
val = val + ((negative) ? -1 : 1); 
negative = (negative) ? false : true;
$("#myval").text(val);
});
```

This function works great on the first click but clicking the second time it doesn't remove the value, is something wrong with the function? here is the button

```
 <button id="myvals" class="myvals">
 <i class="myvals" id="i-t"></i> 
 <span class="myvals" id="voteScore">123</span></button>
```

i want to change the 123 to 124 if liked and 122 if disliked and it doesn't works, i'm sorry i had to prepare the question better from the beginning

Comment: Move `var val = 0; var negative = false;` outside of the handler

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cug5r48y/1/ ?

Comment: your code will make the value `1` on first click, then `0` on second click, then alternate between 1 and 0 on each click ... is this what you expect

Comment: @ArunPJohny what i need is to remove a value and plus it or subtract it from a span class

Comment: sorry... not sure what you mean... do you mean the span already has a value and you want to add or subtract value from that?

Comment: @Iliecucu Please describe what the expected result is on first click, second click, and subsequent clicks - your code does one thing, you say it does another, and you seem to expect some other behaviour without actually being specific

Comment: @ArunPJohny Exactly! I want to change an existing value

Comment: Should you not have two buttons then? One for like and one for dislike?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cug5r48y/2/ ?

Comment: @saranshkataria yes i do have 2 but if you click on the same button it removes the vote but it's visible only after the refresh

Comment: or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cug5r48y/4/

Comment: The statement `negative = (negative) ? false : true;` is simpler as `negative = !negative`.

Comment: @ArunPJohny i don't want to brag you but you are a genius! It Works, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments and update, what you want to do is to increase/decrease the vote count based on whether you have already clicked or not.

In that case, instead of using a variable, you can store the state using a class to support multiple vote button if you need like

```js
$('button.vote').click(function () {
    var $btn = $(this).toggleClass('voted');
    $(this).find("span.score").text(function (i, val) {
        return +val + ($btn.hasClass('voted') ? 1 : -1);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="myvals vote"> <i class="myvals" id="i-t">here</i><span class="myvals score">123</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var val = 0;
var negative = false;
$('.i-t').click(function() {
    val = parseInt($("#voteScore").val()) + ((negative) ? -1 : 1);
    negative = (negative) ? false : true;
    $("#myval").text(val);
});
```

Comment: i made the mistake here, the code was exactly like that, and it doesn't works anyways, any ideas? i tried with (document).ready to and it doesn't works

Comment: Code only answers aren't liked. You should explain the OP's issue and why your code fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

You need two buttons, one for up and one for down, or you could use one button and a checkbox for up or down, but I think two buttons is simpler.

When reading values from DOM elements, they're generally strings so if numbers are required, particularly for addition, don't forget to convert the value to a number before doing arithmetic.

So the buttons and code can be something like:

```js
function vote(n) {
  // Get the element to update
  var el = document.getElementById('votes');

  // Convert the text content to Number, then add value
  el.textContent = Number(el.textContent) + n;
}
```

```html
Votes: <span id="votes">123</span>
<button onclick="vote(1)">up vote</button>
<button onclick="vote(-1)">down vote</button>
```

Of course this is just a demo, adapt it however you wish.